# Convert two pixel in mm and inch on user input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am taking a value from user in cm. Meaning I put one scale which is exactly 1 cm in size user click on starting and ending point of scale and from there I get total no of pixel 1 cm contains. Now I want to convert that pixel in inch how to do that?

```
double a = p2.X - p1.X;
double b = p2.Y - p1.Y;
distance_of_pixcel = (Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b))  ; //Return total no. of pixcel in 1cm

distance_of_pixcel = distance_of_pixcel / 0.39;  //1 cm = 0.393701 inch
```

Is this proper way? I'm not getting the same value every time.

Comment: I'd suggest 3 improvements: 1. Use something bigger than 1 cm - with a worst case pixel density (ppi) of < 50 you can have up ~10% deviation. 2. Use the exact value for converting cm to inch - you are losing another ~1% precision there. You could ask the user to measure the entire width/height of their monitor - that would yield maximum precision and enter that instead of clicking pixels 1 cm apart. Scale width and height independently. Even tough it is standard nowadays to have square pixels, it's possible someone is still using some old monitor with rectangular pixels.

Comment: measure of entire monitor is not possible but if i use 5 cm then it will work ?

Comment: It would certainly improve your precision. It all depends on how precise you need that measurement to be and what kind of effort would be justifiable for that. If your use case is very regional (e.g. only one country) you could ask the user to use something they are likely to be carrying around (multiple options would be ideal), like a common banknote instead. Put a preview of something familiar on the screen so the user can see if his settings are correct. (e.g. drag slider until banknote on screen is the same size as the real one)

Comment: that's nice answer and very help full thank you Manfred

Comment: You are welcome. I'll add it as an answer so you can close this question by marking an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest 3 improvements:

1. **Use something bigger than 1 cm**
   With a worst case pixel density (PPI) of < 50 you can have up ~10% deviation.
2. **Use the exact value for converting cm to inch**
   you are losing another ~1% precision there. You could ask the user to measure the entire width/height of their monitor - that would yield maximum precision and enter that instead of clicking pixels 1 cm apart.
3. **Scale width and height independently**
   Even tough it is standard nowadays to have square pixels, it's possible someone is still using some old monitor with rectangular pixels.

> Measure of entire monitor is not possible but if I use 5 cm then it will work?

It would certainly improve your precision. It all depends on how precise you need that measurement to be and what kind of effort would be *justifiable* for that.

If your use case is very regional (e.g. only one country) you could ask the user to use something they are likely to be carrying around (multiple options would be ideal), like a **common banknote** instead. Put a preview of something familiar on the screen so the user can see if his settings are correct.

E.g.: Drag a slider until banknote on screen is the same size as the real one